# Php code for captcha not working

Tags: forms, validation, captcha

I have been trying with the following codes but nothing displays, please help where I have done wrong. I am very new to php so looking for your assistance on this please.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION["$first_num"])) {
        $_SESSION["$first_num"] = rand(1,10); 
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION["$second_num"])) {
        $_SESSION["$second_num"] = rand(1,10); 
    }
    $operators = array("+", "-", "*");
    $operator = rand(0, count($operators) -1);
    $operator = $operators [$operator];
    $answer = 0;
    switch ($operator) {
    case "+"
    $answer = $first_num + $second_num;
    break;
    case "-":
    $answer = $first_num - $second_num;
    break;
    case "*":
    $answer = $first_num * $second_num;
    break;
    }
    $_SESSION["answer"] = $answer;
    ?>
    <?php
    $answer = $_SESSION["answer"];
    $user_answer = $_POST["answer"];
    if ($answer == $user_answer) {
    echo "Form Submitted Successfully"
    } else {
    echo "Incorrect Captcha try again"
    ?>
```

Comment: There's a pretty good chance that you have errors in your PHP code.  Check your PHP logs, turn on PHP error reporting, etc.  Pro tip: Actually indenting your code to make it more human-readable will help you, as a human, read your code and spot potential problems.  (At first glance, one problem is that your code is missing a semi-colon and at least one closing curly brace at the end.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance I have corrected the following : case "+": and put } at the end  before ?> but still its the same.

Comment: Define “the same”.  What’s the actual error?  What do the PHP error logs say?